# AMP not showing images (404 error)

Tags: amp-html

I have problems with AMP.
For all my URLs with AMP, it doesn't show the images.

Here is a URL with AMP that works:

http://corazon.pe/amp/hombres/mens-heart/9-cosas-que-tal-vez-no-sabias-de-ryan-gosling-y-que-te-haran-amarlo-aun-mas-noticia-1026451

Here is the URL that Google shows: (Open it using chrome device toolbar)

https://www.google.com.pe/amp/corazon.pe/amp/hombres/mens-heart/9-cosas-que-tal-vez-no-sabias-de-ryan-gosling-y-que-te-haran-amarlo-aun-mas-noticia-1026451

As you can see, it correctly shows the images without Google Also, when Google shows the URL, all the images return 404.

I tried purging it but with no luck.

Do you have any ideas so I can try them?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "it correctly shows the images without Google Also, when Google shows the URL, all the images return 404"? Also, have you used the [`amp-img`](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-img) instead of just `img`?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. Yes, it has amp-img. Today I noticed that .PNG images and videos are not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that it was a problem with my images. Those images were supposed to be .PNG but those images were .JPG with extension .PNG.

What we have done to do is verify our image resize process and specify that **if it is a .JPG it always must a .JPG** (the same for .PNG).

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

The Google AMP Cache fetches and caches your AMPs including linked assets such as fonts, videos and images. In your case, it looks like you're blocking access to your images from outside your domain (e.g. https://e.radio-corazon.io/medium/2017/01/26/182918_334273.png can't be opened in a browser). This means the cache is unable to fetch your images and hence isn't able to serve them together with your AMP.

Comment: Hi, good answer but our URLs are not working with SSL/HTTPS. We are working only with HTTP. Or AMP requires HTTPS?

Comment: Sorry - my fault, not sure how the https got into the link. AMP doesn't not require images to be served via https. The AMP Cache doesn't seem to be able to access the image on your server. This should work: https://cdn.ampproject.org/i/e.radio-corazon.io/medium/2017/01/26/182918_334273.png. The crawler not being able to access images usually results from access being blocked via robots.txt or headers. Neither seems to be the case in your sample though.

Comment: I know it somehow weird, but do you know if AMP works with .png and .mp4 files? Because, all my .jpg works but .png and .mp4 not at all.

Comment: The Cache supports png and mp4. Is there anything different in how you serve jpg vs mp4 and png?

Comment: How so?. As far as I know there nothing different. For videos, I work with AWS Transcoder to resize videos, for images, I just work with AWS S3. Lambda, nodejs and imagemagick.